# Pagination in Gmail API (Previous Token)

Tags: laravel-5, google-api, pagination, token, gmail-api

I have implemented GMail API which gets Emails for me. Now I am trying to add pagination to it I have succeed in getting next records but now I also want to have Previous option(which required previous token).

I am unable to get into it below is what I tried so far.

```
public function paginate(Request $request){
        $label =  $request->input("label");
        $nextToken =  $request->input("next");
        $prevToken =  $request->input("prev");
        $messages = LaravelGmail::message();
        $msg = $messages->take(3)->in($label)->all($nextToken);
        $nextToken_New = $messages->pageToken;

        return view('gmail.load_mails', ['messages' => $msg, 'nextPageToken' => $nextToken_New,
        'prevPageToken' => $nextToken]);
}
```

Now In the above function nextPageToken is passed in view as `$nextToken_New`
and for prevPageToken I am unable to set previous page token.(In code I have set last nextPageToken to `prevPageToken` which is not working)

Remember `prevPageToken` will be used to set on back key.

Comment: Your going to have to save the previous page token yourself somewhere.  The api does not return that to you.

Comment: Yes I do know API does not give it but that is what I am looking for how do I implement it using nextPagetoken itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gmail api does not support prevous page token. Its not going to return the value to you.

Your first option would be to save these tokens on your server and then when ever you want to go back a page simply supply the token you want to the page token field

The second option and the one that i personally feel would be the most logical.  Would be to cache the data returned by these requests on your server so that

1. you dont have to make extra http calls to the server.
2. you are not eating addictal quota making a call you have already made before.

APIs were not meant for you to use to implement pagination in your application.  You should  only be requesting data once its your job to then cache that data so that you wont need to make the same request twice.

Comment: Okay you mean to say just get all the emails at single(or in lots of 100) HTTP call and cache them somewhere and then apply pagination to it

Comment: Exactly. Cache them somewhere.  store the data you dont need to be requesting this data form google all the time.

Comment: What if I have cache 100 emails and then new message is arrives in my gmail inbox how do I then get to know that new message has been received and refresh them

Comment: Yes you would have to do that anyway any new messages would not have been part of any next page token you got back from Google.   I would just compair the id to see if you have it already.

Comment: Great also let me know what would be better to store those emails ? Db or somewhere else like cookies

Comment: I do not think that you can store that much data in cookies.  I would recommend a database of some type.  Remember to document what you are doing you will need the information when you apply to have the application verified by google as Gmail is one of the sensitive scopes and you are storing user data you will need to be able to verify you are keeping this data secure.

Comment: Hmmm okay I got you.